# MySql and PHPMyAdmin password

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, database-connection

I was given an username, password, database name and an url for accessing the phpmyadmin console for a specific application. Now I want to connect to the database, which ip address I also know.

I tried running the following php snippet (from my local installation of xampp), which gave me an error, saying:

"Warning: mysql_connect(): Access denied for user 'xxxxxxx'@'localhost' "

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<?php
$username = "given_username";  
$password = "given_password"; 
$db_name  = "given_database_name"; 
$hostname = "xxxxx:3306"; //remote address

//connection to the database
$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) 
  or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
echo "Connected to MySQL<br>";

?>  

</body>
</html>
```

My question is: Are the password and username for mysql and phpmyadmin the same, and, am I running this correctly?

Comment: The mysql user you were given most likely only has access from the localhost, ie- the system running the mysql server itself, and does not hav e remote access.

Comment: You can easily test that using telnet: `telnet <ip> 3006`... if it times out then you cannot connect remotely like that.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your question, I assume the php code and the MySQL server run on different machines. In that case, you have to create a remote user in your MySQL server.

1. Login to your MySQL console on the MySQL server:

   mysql -u root -p
2. Grant access to remote user

   mysql> GRANT ALL ON given_database_name.* TO given_username@'*<ip address of the php server*>' IDENTIFIED BY 'given_password';

Now you should be able to connect MySQL from remote machine. If your MySQL server is behind a firewall, make sure you open incoming port of MySQL (default is 3306).